# Find amounts of files and get total line count with Node FS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, fs

I'm building a node script asynchronously outputs a directory's file count and line count; however, I am having trouble with its asynchronous control flow.

```
// Import Dependencies
const fs = require('fs');

const get_dir_line_count = (dir) => {
  let output = { file_count: 0, file_line: 0, path: '' };
  new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(dir, (err, dir_contents) => {
      resolve(dir_contents);
    });
  }).then( (promise_contents) => {
    Promise.all(promise_contents.map( (file) => {
      const file_path = dir + '/' + file;
      return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        fs.stat(file_path, (err, stat) => {
          if(err || file[0] === '.') return err;
          if(stat.isDirectory() && file !== 'node_modules'){
            get_dir_line_count(file_path);
          }
          else if(stat.isFile()){
            promise_line_count(file_path)
              .then( (line_count) => {
                output.path = dir;
                output.file_line += line_count;
                output.file_count++;
                resolve(output);
              });
          };
        });
      }).then( (resolved_output) => {
        console.log(resolved_output)
        return resolved_output;
      });
    }));
  });

};

const promise_line_count = (pathToFile) => {
  let line_count = 0;
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    fs.createReadStream(pathToFile)
      .on("data", (buffer) => {
        buffer.forEach( (chunk) => {
          if(chunk === 10) line_count++;
        });
      }).on("end", () => {
        resolve(line_count);
      });
  });
};

const directory = process.argv[2];
get_dir_line_count('./../' + directory);
```

My intention is to recursively go through the directories that outputs Promise.all arrays. Each array is a collection of the directory's computed data. However, I am having asynchronous control flow issue upon the Promise.all. If anyone can provide feedback, that would be helpful.

Output:

Project = 5 Files, 50 lines

Project/src = 10 Files, 60 lines

Project/apple = 20 Files, 200 lines

...etc

Comment: your problem is `if(stat.isDirectory() && file !== 'node_modules'){
            get_dir_line_count(file_path);
          }` - the Promise will forever remain unresolved

Comment: also `get_dir_line_count` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that you're not returning anything from `get_dir_line_count` function itself:

```
const get_dir_line_count = (dir) => {
  let output = { file_count: 0, file_line: 0, path: '' };
  new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
// ^---- missing a return statement
```

Another problem is that you forgot to return the result from `Promise.all` so the chain can be properly built:

```
// ...
}).then( (promise_contents) => {
    Promise.all(promise_contents.map( (file) => {
// ^---- missing a return
```

You've also forgotten to return (or resolve) the recursive call to `get_dir_line_count`:

```
if(err || file[0] === '.') return err;
  if(stat.isDirectory() && file !== 'node_modules'){
    get_dir_line_count(file_path);
  // ^--- missing a return statement or resolve statement
  }
```

Finally, since you're returning the output object from `get_dir_line_count`, you can check things work by adding a `then` and passing the result into `console.log`:

```
const directory = process.argv[2];
get_dir_line_count('./../' + directory).then(console.log) // <-- get the output object and the log it
```

---

As far as dealing with the complexity of asynchronous code in general, main thing you can do to clean up the control flow is to extract individual logic into separate functions.

Bellow you can find a code example of one approach along with embedded comments (I also preserved the underscored naming preference):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// resolves with the file names within the given directory
function get_file_names(dir) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(dir, (err, fileNames) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(fileNames);
    });
  });
}

// resolves with an object containing the type ('file' or 'dir') for the given file path and the file path itself: { file_path, type }
function get_path_and_type(file_path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.stat(file_path, (err, stat) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      if (!stat.isDirectory() && !stat.isFile()) reject('Invalid Type');
      const type = stat.isDirectory() ? 'dir' : 'file';
      resolve({
        file_path,
        type
      });
    });
  });
}

// same as before, counts lines for the given file path
function count_lines(file_path) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let lineCount = 0;
    fs.createReadStream(file_path)
      .on("data", (buffer) => {
        buffer.forEach((chunk) => {
          if (chunk === 10) lineCount++;
        });
      }).on("end", () => {
        resolve(lineCount);
      }).on("error", reject);
  });
};

function get_dir_line_count(dir) {

  const output = {
    file_count: 0,
    file_lines: 0,
    path: dir
  };

  // get all filenames in the given directory
  return get_file_names(dir)
    // filter all file names that start with a '.' or include the string 'node_modules'
    .then((names) =>
      names.filter((name) =>
        !name.startsWith('.') && !name.includes('node_modules')
      )
    )
    // map every file name into a promise that resolves with the type for that file name within the given dir
    .then((names) =>
      names.map((name) =>
        get_path_and_type(path.join(dir, name))
        .catch(console.warn) // log invalid typed files if necessary
      )
    ).then((paths_and_types_promises) =>
      Promise.all(paths_and_types_promises.map((promise) =>
        promise.then(({
          file_path,
          type
        }) => {
          if (type === 'dir') {
            // if current file path corresponds to a directory
            // recursive count its files and lines and add it to the overall output
            return get_dir_line_count(file_path)
              .then((recursive_output) => {
                output.file_count += recursive_output.file_count;
                output.file_lines += recursive_output.file_count;
              });
          } else {
            // count the lines for the current file path and then update the overall output
            return count_lines(file_path)
              .then((file_lines) => {
                output.file_lines += file_lines;
                output.file_count += 1;
              })
          }
        })
      ))
    // this last chain makes sure we wait for the promise to resolve
    // and populate the output object before resolving with it
    ).then(() => output);
}

get_dir_line_count(process.argv[2])
  .then(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks! I re-wrote the my code so many times that I got stumped and I decided to resort to Stack!

Comment: No problem mate, glad to help :)

Comment: I think the only issue I'm having with the code above is logging the initial directory's content. I'm getting an Unhandled Promise rejection warning.

Comment: What do you mean? Is there a specific error? Does this happen when you run the whole code or just `get_file_names` function? The best way to determine what is happening is to add a `catch` at the end: `get_dir_line_count(process.argv[2]).then(console.log).catch(console.error)` and inspect what the error is

Comment: There's a small bug on line 77-83. Recursive output will throw an error for the root directory because there isn't a defined output. So I added a simple conditional which solves it.

Thanks for the advice and help everyone! It's performing exactly how I wanted it to perform.

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
let output = {};
let lastDir = '';

const walk = (dir) => {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        output[dir] = {
            files: 0,
            lines: 0,
            path: ''
        };

        fs.readdir(dir, (err, list) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            let pending = list.length;

            if (!pending) {
                return resolve(output);
            }

            list.forEach((file) => {
                file = path.resolve(dir, file);

                fs.stat(file, (err, stat) => {
                    if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                        walk(file)
                            .then((res) => {
                                if (!--pending) {             
                                    resolve(output);
                                }
                            })
                    }
                    else {
                        let lc = 0;

                        fs.createReadStream(file)
                            .on('data', (buffer) => {
                                buffer.forEach((chunk) => {
                                    if (chunk === 10) {
                                        lc++;
                                    }
                                })
                            })
                            .on('end', () => {
                                output[dir].files++;
                                output[dir].lines += lc;
                                output[dir].path = dir;

                                if (!--pending) {
                                    resolve(output);
                                }
                            });
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    });
};

walk('.')
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.log);
```